# Why I'm not being able to display a dashboard in Shiny (R)?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I'm new in shiny apps in R so by now i'm trying to make a simple dashboard by using next code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyUI(
    dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody()
    )
)
```

the problem here is when I execute the script I get next error message:

[image]

I've already tried to install the package going to 'Tools' section and also by using:

```
install.packages('bslib')
```

But is not working, could you tell me what is wrong here? thanks by the way.

Comment: thanks but I tried that already, also I reinstalled R and Rstudio but is still not working :(

Comment: can you show your `packageVersion('shiny')` and `packageVersion('shinydashboard')`

Comment: sure i got this result: packageVersion('shiny') :[1] ‘1.6.0’ and
packageVersion('shinydashboard') [1] ‘0.7.1’

Comment: I have an older version of shiny 1.5.0 that may be the reason and shinydashboard is same version

Comment: Do I need to download R Studio Server to run it?

Comment: I run this on rstudio desktop